# Cantor's diagonalization argument - define second sequence, that is also not in the list.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I now how the standard construction of a sequence which can not be in the list, but how can i construction  another sequence which is not in the list ? 
More generally, is it possible to list all sequence which are not in the list ( of course their are infinitely many).

Comment: You want to list an uncountable set?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "list" - obviously there's no list *in the usual sense* (= indexed by natural numbers), since otherwise we could put the two lists together and get a list containing all sequences.

Comment: Can you just take the same sequence, but strike out an arbitrary element?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have constructed a sequence not in the list that putatively enumerates all the elements of the set, you can put this sequence at the beginning of the list and run the same diagonal argument on this new list to construct a second sequence not in the new list, and thus in the original list.

This can be repeated countably infinitely many times, interleaving the original list and the list of new sequences, but the new sequences will never exhaust all the elements that were missing from the original list, because the overall set is uncountably infinite and the augmented list only remains countably infinite.

Comment: You cannot put a countably infinite list at the beginning of another countably infinite list. But I suspect that is not what you really meant.

Comment: @String At least you can interleave the two lists together.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought you wanted to say, but I am not sure that is what your post says now. :)

Comment: @String I just edited to put this clarification in. :)

Comment: You fixed it in the second paragraph, yes. What about the first?

Comment: @String I do not put countably infinitely many lists at the beginning in the first paragraph, only one.

Comment: Yes, but that sequence could be contably infinite itself, right?

Comment: @String Not a countably infinite _number of lists_. The other sequences in the list are already countably infinite; our index runs only over the sequences themselves and not the elements of sequences.

Comment: I am sorry for not getting this, but what does the sequence mentioned in the first paragraph contain? Some numbers or some lists of numbers? I feel like I am being unnecesarily difficult right now, but then again I am not clear on what you mean.

Comment: @String The extra sequence constructed in paragraph 1 is merely a set of numbers, not a list of set of numbers. Braces can kill...

Comment: OK, then my original question remains: Does a sequence of numbers not in the original list have to be finite? I think it could well be countably infinite and thus would require interleaving. Unless we state specifically that it is finite.

Comment: @String It doesn't have to be, since it is merely one set.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the first mentioned sequence does not have to be finite, but could be countably infinite. You cannot put such an infinite sequence at the beginning of anything, since it has no end. Unless you mean to put the set as a single entity as the first element of the list of sequences, and not to put it at the beginning of the original list. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @String That is what I meant, yes.

Comment: I see! The next sentence is what threw me off then, since you say that we can then use the diagonal argument on this new list. Which new list? The list resulting from interleaving the original list with the sequence we just discussed?

Comment: @String Yes! Interleaving the list of one new sequence of numbers with the original list.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Sorry for being difficult.